# Utilizing Client Application Users' Devices as Peer Nodes in Hyperledger Fabric Network

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I'm working on a project that involves building a decentralized social media platform using Hyperledger Fabric. One of the key requirements is to utilize the storage and computing power of client application users' devices as peer nodes in the network. I want to configure the client application in a way that allows it to act as a peer node and contribute to the blockchain network.

I have knowledge of how Hyperledger Fabric works and its core components, but I'm unsure about the specific steps or the Fabric SDK classes/functions that can help me achieve this configuration. Can someone provide guidance on how to configure the client application users' devices as peer nodes in the Hyperledger Fabric network? Any insights, code snippets, or references to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Note: The client application is built using Node.js, and I'm using the latest version of Hyperledger Fabric (v2.x).

I have thoroughly researched the Hyperledger Fabric documentation and explored various online resources, including tutorials and sample projects. However, I haven't found specific information or examples related to configuring client application users' devices as peer nodes in the Fabric network.

I expected to find some guidance or code examples that demonstrate how to enable client devices to participate as peer nodes and contribute their storage and computing power to the blockchain network. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a direct solution or clear documentation addressing this particular requirement.

I'm reaching out to the Stack Overflow community to seek expert advice and guidance on how to accomplish this configuration in Hyperledger Fabric. Any insights, suggestions, or code snippets would be greatly appreciated.